# Child of an xElement within LINQ Query

Tags: c#, xml, linq, nodes, xelement

How do I get an child element of an xElement in the example below:

I am using LINQ to query some XML data, but I can't seem to get to the part of the XML from which I want the data.

Here's my code so far:

```
// Use LINQ to pipe the data in to OrderSummary objects
var linqQuery = from n in customer_orders.Element("ROOT").Descendants("TOEHEAD")
                select new OrderSummary
                {
                    order_date = n.Element("DATEONFILE_MV").ToString(),
                };
```

This code returns the `order_date` as:

```
<DATEONFILE_MV>
  <DATEONFILE>08/08/12</DATEONFILE>
</DATEONFILE_MV>
```

But I just want the date from within the `DATEONFILE` tags.  At the moment it is an XElement and I can't find a way to just request the `<dateonfile>` element which is a child node of it.

I thought that just putting `n.Element("DATEONFILE")` would work, but sadly not, because it's a child node of `<DATEONFILE_MV>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var linqQuery = from n in customer_orders.Element("ROOT").Descendants("TOEHEAD")
                select new OrderSummary
                {
                    order_date = n.Descendants("DATEONFILE").First().Value,
                };
```